# MapKit Xcode 4.5.2

Tags: xcode, annotations, mapkit

I am new to app development and I am trying to create a relatively simple app. The first thing I need to create is a map with some customizable features. I can get the map framework loaded fine and I can get it to run in the simulator with the current location, however I cannot make the map zoom in to my current location nor can I add custom annotations. I have followed many tutorials but I am assuming they are not working because xcode 4.5.2 is so new and is different. If possible could anyone explain the process to me. Ideally I would appreciate if somebody has a code I can copy and paste in order to see what mistakes I am making within my coding.

Comment: "I cannot make the map zoom in to my current location nor can I add custom annotations" -- you might want to clarify what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened. It'll give the experts more to go on.

Comment: I will try to be more specific in the future. I did figure it out based in the responses given. Thanks and bare with me this is all new to me.

Comment: Great! It's good form to accept an answer, if there is one that solved your issue or best answered your question. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   //This piece of code zooms into the User Location:
     - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView


        (MKUserLocation *)userLocation {
            MKCoordinateRegion mapRegion;   
            mapRegion.center = map.userLocation.coordinate;
            mapRegion.span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.2, 0.2);
            [map setRegion:mapRegion animated: YES];
        }
```

Check out this link if you need more help: http://www.altinkonline.nl/tutorials/xcode/corelocation/add-an-annotation-to-a-mapview/

Check out this link to extract data from an online source: http://raywenderlich.com/2847/introduction-to-mapkit-on-ios-tutoria‌​l

Answer (score 0):

Apple wrote the LocationAwareness guide. This explains all you need.
In simulator you have to enable GPS simulation. The default simulation track shows positions in San Francisco.